# Table value returning nil?

Tags: random, lua

I'm making a random word generator, and I've run in a little problem. I'm trying to print values from a table holding closedLetters (c, d, f, etc) but it's not working. It's returning nil. Help?

```
local closedLetters={b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, z}
local openLetters={a, e, i, o, u, y}
print(closedLetters[2])
```

(that piece of code is just an example, what I had set up was actually more like this)

```
local closedLetters={b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, z}
local openLetters={a, e, i, o, u, y}
print(closedLetters[math.random(#closedLetters)]..openLetters[math.random(#openLetters)])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only a bunch of keys in that table. Keys with nil values, hence your return value.
Make them literals instead: 
closedLetters= {'a', 'b', .....}

Answer (score 2):

To complement Eyeball's answer, you can just make `closedLetters` and `openLetters` actual strings. You can then use `string.sub` to access them:

```
local closedLetters = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
local openLetters   = "aeiouy"
local letter1, letter2 = math.random(#closedLetters), math.random(#openLetters)
print(closedLetters:sub(letter1, letter1) .. openLetters:sub(letter2, letter2) )
```

Comment: This is awesome, and convenient ofc. However, since 'everything is tables' in lua. I think our solutions are basically the same under the hood :)

Comment: @Eyeball actually strings aren't tables under the hood. Tables are mutable, strings are not.